# Unique rows in OnetoOne relation case . How to prevent duplicates?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a question about the code. I want the rows to be unique. For flight, I just use the @UniqueConstraint annotation, and it works fine.

However, in the case of Hotel, he writes a duplicate to my database.

I suspect that this is due to the fact that the tables are connected by a one-to-one relationship.

I assure you have to write it in a flight class, not a hotel.

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name = "Flight", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"departure","currency","destination","price","flightnumber","airline","departuretime","returntime","expiresAt","userName","airlineIata" }))
public class Flight {

    private Long id;

    private String departure;

    private String currency;

    private String destination;
```

... etc

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name = "Hotel", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"site","rating","phone","name","longitude","latitude","image3","image2","image","hotelLink","describe","currency","category","address","price" }))

public class Hotel {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String currency;
    private String site;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String address;
    private Double rating;
    private String image;
    private String image2;
    private String image3;
    private String hotelLink;
    private String phone;
    private String describe;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String category;
```

getters ... and setters ...

```
some code....

  hotel.setPrice(hotelCurrencyService.amountCalculator(array.getVendor3Price(), exchangeRate));
```

flight.setDeparture(flightDTO.getDeparture());
    some code .....

```
 flight.setHotel(hotel);
 flightRepository.save(flight);
```

Answer (score 0):

This hotel it's previously save? Or save method persist both entities (Flight and Hotel)?
On my projects, I aways try get the object from database, and then, if already exist the object I implement rules for update or abort.

Comment: Save method persist both entities